# NSCollectionViewDelegate not called when using Content Array (Legacy) layout

Tags: objective-c, swift, nscollectionview

I have different NSCollectionView's that use NSCollectionViewDelegate. When I use a Flow or a Grid layout, the delegates functions are called, but not with the Content Array (Legacy) layout.

Of course the collectionView.delegate is set correctly as it works with other layout.

Does somebody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably Legacy Collection View isn't maintained so it could be a bug. Apple says "You are encouraged to use the modern collection view architecture when configuring collection views in macOS 10.11 and later. Use the legacy architecture only for apps that must run in earlier versions of macOS.". If you still want to use Legacy Collection View then post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke Sorry for my late reply. I need to use the legacy layout because the application I'm working on must run on macOS 10.9. But I figured it out while writing a minimal reproducible example... I was expecting canDragItems and writeItemsAt to be called with IndexPaths, but on the content Array layout there are no IndexPaths. canDragItemsAt with IndexSet is called. Most of other delegates are only for flow and grid layout.